Is there a name for this complexity class?
Let me use the ad hoc name weak-$BQP$ for the class obtained from $BQP$ by the following modification: Given a problem instance $x$ with correct solution $y\in \{0, 1 \}^n$, the circuit $C_{|x|}$ satisfies $|\left<z\middle|C_{|x|} \left |0 \right>\right>| < |\left<y\middle|C_{|x|} \left |0 \right>\right>|$ for every $y \neq z\in \{0, 1\}^n$ (so there is an efficient way to construct a circuit that provides a correct answer, but we might need a large number of measurements to obtain it).

Has anyone already studied this complexity class?
How does it relate to other known complexity classes?


My guess is something like PP?

Are there any restrictions on the scaling of $|\langle y| C | 0 \rangle|$ in problem size?. If it is bounded by a constant, then what you describe sounds pretty much like BQP. If it is allowed to arbitrarily decay, then it feels like you could even have PSPACE problems in there.

@RefikMansuroglu I'm not assuming any such restriction.

Your class could be very powerful, then, couldn't it?  $|\left<z\middle|C_{|x|} \left |0 \right>\right>|$ could be only $\varepsilon$ less than $ |\left<y\middle|C_{|x|} \left |0 \right>\right>|$.

@MarkSpinelli Indeed, that's what my intuition is telling me. I was hoping that perhaps there is an easy way to see, e.g., that $PSPACE \subseteq weak-BQP$.

@a travelling salesman
It should be straight-forward to show that approximate optimization is in weak-BQP, which implies $NP \subseteq weak-BQP$.
For PSPACE, I would try to encode a quantified Boolean formula in a quantum state similar to the 3-SAT reduction to Ising type Hamiltonians.

Because the output is a string $y$ rather than a boolean value, I guess we're talking about function problems not decision problems. That makes comparisons with $\mathrm{BQP}$ and other classes of decision problems tricky. Have you considered formulating a decision problem variant? If you do that, my guess is similar to Mark's: this looks like $\mathrm{PP}$ (or maybe something inside $\mathrm{NP}\cdot\mathrm{PP},$ depending on the specifics).

I second John's and Mark's guess -- with an arbitrarily small separation if looks like postselected BQP (PostBQP), which equals PP But it might depend on how precisely you formulate the decision variant. The way it is phrased now the first guess for a decision class is is that you have BQP with a different postselection which allows you to select the basis state with the largest amplitude, which is not entirely evident whether it would be equal to PostBQP.
